# In SQL/ORACLE how do I find the date that is 14 NON WEEKEND days prior to yesterday's date?

Tags: oracle, date

In SQL/ORACLE I need to output the date that is 14 non weekend days (excluding SAT/SUN) prior to yesterday's date (today - 1).

For example if today is 05-MAY-16 I would need:

04-MAY-16 = yesterday

14-APR-16 = 14 non weekend days back

The below helps me find yesterday's date (excluding weekend as date):

```
SELECT decode(to_char(sysdate,'dy'),'sun',sysdate-2,'tue',sysdate-3,sysdate-1) from dual
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about holidays? Are you still counting those as business days and really just excluding Sat/Sun? You'd need a calendar table to exclude holidays, of course...

Comment: That is true, however the data would be used by America and London based teams so not as sure how that would work with two different holiday calendars. For now I think modifying it to 14 days back (non weekends) instead of 14 days back (business days) would be sufficient.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the counting method. If today is Friday, yesterday was Thursday - is that already the first work day you want in the count backwards, or is Wednesday the first day? I assume Wednesday (that is "one work day prior to yesterday.")  Then, if today is Saturday, one work day prior to yesterday is Thursday. What if today is Sunday or Monday? Do you count Friday prior as "one work day prior to yesterday" or is that "count zero" and the Thursday prior is "one work day prior to 'yesterday' "?

Answer (score 4):

If you really only want to skip weekends and don't wan to take other holidays into account at all, you could use a recursive CTE, with the anchor branch starting at yesterday, and the recursive branch counting back while ignoring the weekend days, until you've reached far enough back.

You could generate the dates with something like:

```
with r (the_date, days_ago, work_days_ago) as (
  select trunc(sysdate) - 1, 0, 0
  from dual
  union all
  select r.the_date - 1, days_ago + 1,
    work_days_ago + case
      when to_char(r.the_date - 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
        in ('SAT','SUN') then 0 else 1 end
  from r
  where days_ago < 28
  and work_days_ago < 14
)
select r.*, to_char(r.the_date, 'DY')
from r;

THE_DATE    DAYS_AGO WORK_DAYS_AGO TO_CHAR(R.TH
--------- ---------- ------------- ------------
04-MAY-16      0         0 WED
03-MAY-16      1         1 TUE
02-MAY-16      2         2 MON
01-MAY-16      3         2 SUN
30-APR-16      4         2 SAT
29-APR-16      5         3 FRI
28-APR-16      6         4 THU
27-APR-16      7         5 WED
26-APR-16      8         6 TUE
25-APR-16      9         7 MON
24-APR-16     10         7 SUN
23-APR-16     11         7 SAT
22-APR-16     12         8 FRI
21-APR-16     13         9 THU
20-APR-16     14        10 WED
19-APR-16     15        11 TUE
18-APR-16     16        12 MON
17-APR-16     17        12 SUN
16-APR-16     18        12 SAT
15-APR-16     19        13 FRI
14-APR-16     20        14 THU
```

And to get the one you want:

```
...
select max(the_date)
from r
where work_days_ago = 14;

MAX(THE_D
---------
14-APR-16
```

In the recursive branch the `days_ago < 28` is just to give a static stop condition for the recursion; it won't ever reach that but it needs to be high enough so you can be sure of that. Then the `work_days_ago < 14` stops it looking any further back than you actually need. You can't *only* check that because you'd get a loop as soon as you hit a weekend, since the number wouldn't increment.

In the outer query I've used max in case you ran it on a Tuesday; then the recursion would get three days all with `work_days_ago` as 14, representing the Monday, Sunday and Saturday; and you only want the most recent of those. (Or, instead of `max()`, explicitly exclude weekend days again).

Comment: brilliant! I guess you dont have to go as far as back to 28 days isnt it? Should 20 be not good enough?

Comment: @cableload - maybe, I had it as 21 to start with; but going higher doesn't hurt as the `work_days_ago` check will break the recursion before it hits the `days_ago` limit anyway, so it isn't costing you anything.

Comment: you are brilliant!

Comment: Missed the simple solution though...   :-)

Comment: @mathguy - me, overthink a solution? Surely not?? I may have thought the requirement was going to get more complicated and this could be adapted to look for holidays, but seems that isn't needed. (Plus, any excuse to use a recursive CTE... *8-)

Comment: Right- and a recursive CTE may work when there are holidays too. I just answered a more complicated question (including holidays) this morning on OTN - different setup though, more amenable to what some call the "tabibitosan" method.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is only for weekdays vs. weekend, there is no need for complicated solutions. Something as easy as the code below is enough.

The OP did not respond to my request for clarification, so I need to make an assumption. The code below interprets the requirement as follows:

Starting from today's date, go back on the calendar and count backwards, work days only. The most recent work day gets the count 0, the next one 1, and we return the work day where count = 14. (However, the code doesn't get the answer by counting; based on the requirement as described, it uses a trivial arithmetic computation by cases.)

If the requirement is different, the solution can be modified in the same spirit; regardless of the requirement, the solution should be equally simple.

```
select trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'DY') when 'SAT' then 19
                                                    when 'SUN' then 20
                                                    else            21 end
from ...  (etc.)
```

(Corrected based on Alex's observation in comment below - thanks Alex!)

Comment: Not sure that's quite right - running it tomorrow will give 18-Apr-16, instead of 15-Apr-16, but that might be the clarification you were asking for. Seems wrong to have four days a week go back to a Monday though. 'Fixing' that  would just need the FRI case removing, but I can't tell what should happen.

Comment: I counted the days wrong; if "today" is Friday, I counted Friday as day 0. My mistake - I will correct it in my formula. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

Business days is a hard problem.  This is due to holidays that are different in every country, sometimes within the country.  Holidays can fall on different days like Easter and can be observed on different days.

You will need a custom package to calculate this and a table listing the holidays  and weekends for each year. (assuming you do not work on weekends)

Are you calculating this for one location or multiple locations across a country?

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE HOLIDAYS as
( ID NUMBER(9), --primary key
HOLIDAY_ID NUMBER(9),
FOR_YEAR NUMBER(9),  -- a constraint FOR_YEAR > 1 and < 9999
HOLIDAY_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
HOLIDAY_LENGTH NUMBER(9) DEFAULT 1,
LOCATION_ID NUMBER(9),
HOLIDAY_DATE DATE);
```

--add a unique key on FOR_YEAR,LOCATION_ID, HOLIDAY_ID
--insert every holiday and weekend for each year
and another table of locations where you conduct business

In a package your calculation would be along the lines of

```
FUNCTION GET_BUSINESS_DAYS(start_date_in IN DATE, end_date_in DATE)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
v_days NUMBER(9);
v_holidays NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
--check that start_date_in and end_date_in are valid dates
--check that end_date_in is after start_date_in

--assumes holidays are only one day which is wrong in some cultures!
SELECT start_date_in - end_date_in 
INTO v_days 
FROM DUAL;

SELECT SUM(HOLIDAY_LENGTH) 
INTO v_holidays
FROM HOLIDAYS
WHERE HOLIDAY_DATE BETWEEN start_date_in and end_date_in;

v_days := v_days - v_holidays;
--check that is this a positive value
RETURN v_days;
END GET_BUSINESS_DAYS;
```

There are many edge cases to check on this but this should point you in right

Comment: based on OP's question, the end_date is not known..that is to be calculated...(if the start_date is assumed to be yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It is a function call that requires only two values (although three are provided for override).  The parameters are day (the date you want to start from), days (the number of days to calculate, in your case -14

```
   function AddDays(day in date,days in number,WeekMask in char) 
            return date
   is
      begin
      declare
        NumWorkDays number := 0;  /* Cumultive total for work days */
        WorkDaysPerWeek number := 0;
        FullWeeks number := 0;  /* the number of 7-day weeks encompased by
                                   the specified number of work days. To
                                   wit, trunc(days/WorkDaysPerWeek) */
        LastPartial number := 0; /* number of days in the trailing
                                    partial week.  */
        CurDow number;           /* Current Day of Week for Partial use */
        WMask char(7) := 'YYYYYYY';  /* local copy of WeekMask with default
                                        value - No weekends */
        direct number := 1;
        begin
          /* copy Weekmask to local variable if it is defined, otherwise
             implicitly use default mask */
          direct := sign(days);
          if direct = 0 then direct := 1; end if;
          if WeekMask is not null then WMask := WeekMask; end if;
          for CurDow in 1..7 loop     /* go through mask counting work days */
            if substr(WMask,CurDow,1) = 'Y' then /* if a weekday, count it*/
              WorkDaysPerWeek := WorkDaysPerWeek + 1;
            end if;
          end loop;
          /* determine number of Full weeks (7-day calendar) */
          FullWeeks := trunc(days/WorkDaysPerWeek);
          /* if the number of days is an integer number of Work Weeks
             then decrement the number of Full Weeks so that the
             iterative process will operate on the last week.  This is
             done so that weekend days are not used as ending days */
          if FullWeeks != 0 and mod(days,WorkDaysPerWeek) = 0 then
            FullWeeks := FullWeeks - direct;
          end if;
          /* Compute number of working days found so far */
          NumWorkDays := FullWeeks*WorkDaysPerWeek;
          /* Now go day by day through the last days of the period */
          CurDow := to_number(to_char(day+FullWeeks*7,'D'));
          NumWorkDays := NumWorkDays - direct;
          while NumWorkDays != days loop
            if substr(WMask,CurDow,1) = 'Y' then
              NumWorkDays := NumWorkDays + direct;
            end if;
            If NumWorkDays = days then exit; end if;
            LastPartial := LastPartial + direct;
            CurDow := mod(CurDow+direct+6,7)+1;
          end loop;
          dout := day+FullWeeks*7+LastPartial; /* end date is number
                                                  weeks * 7 plus
                                                  number of additional days*/
    return dout;
        en 
 d;
      end;
```